# Как можно блокировать ботов в nginx?

Tags: nginx, centos, бот

Какие есть способы определения является ли посетитель ботом? В последнее время их у меня развелось очень много. У всех ботов разные  IP. Иногда они могут “долбить” по одному URL- адресу, накручивая статистику сайта. Причем блокировка должна происходить на уровне сервера (nginx).

UPD.

Просмотревши логии, заметил одну особенность:  практически у всех ботов русские IP и параметр http_referer начинается с http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru;search;web;;&text=&etext=829.BBtBI...

Подскажите что это за боты и как в nginx блокировать ботов с таким параметром http_referer.

Comment: Вот кое-какие настройки по блокировке https://github.com/mariusv/nginx-badbot-blocker

Comment: этот точно боты, а не поисковый трафик с Яндекса? Блокировать можно так:  `if ($http_referer ~* (здесь регулярка, напр. jsredir?from=yandex) ) { return 405; }` Но так можете и легитимный трафик с Яндекса отвергнуть.

Comment: Яндекс боты имеют параметр http_user_agent  “compatible;YandexBot/3.0 “.

А эти боты шифруются под обычных пользователей и параметр http_user_agent может быть похож на “compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0”

Answer (score 1):

[fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) спасает от части атак, анализируя логи. В т.ч. он умеет по логам nginx определять атаки и блокировать их источники.

Вот [инструкция](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04) (на англ.) для Nginx на Ubuntu, а вот просто [установка fail2ban на CentOS](http://www.servermom.org/install-fail2ban-centos/1809/) (на англ.)

Но для отлова ботов в вашем понимании придётся разобраться в их признаках очень подробно, и, видимо, написать собственные дополнительные фильтры к fail2ban.

Принцип действия простой: f2b смотрит на логи, если видит там определенные признаки, блокирует ip адреса, с которых эти действия выполнялись. На час, сутки, навсегда – как настроете.